# django join using foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to django 2.7. I am trying to run a join query using foreign key constraint. I have two tables table1 and table2 with following attributes-:

`Model.py`-:

```
class table1(models.Model):
    abcid = models.IntegerField(db_column='abcid', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    abcName = models.CharField(db_column='abcName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    abcyear = models.IntegerField(db_column='abcYear', blank=True, null=True)



class table2(models.Model):
    abcid = models.ForeignKey('table1', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='abcid')
    xyzname = models.CharField(db_column='xyzName', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    xyztype = models.CharField(db_column='xyzType', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

I want to get all the records whose xyzname contains 'pineapple'.
Columns that i need are -`abcid,abcname,abcyear,xyzname`

what i have tried so far are below-:

```
table1.objects.filter(table2__xyzname__icontains = 'pineapple')

table2.objects.filter(xyzname__icontains= 'pineapple').table1_set.all()
```

Please Help.
Error-:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/abc/trade/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'abc_act']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcNew/abc_journal/abcjournal/abcsoft/abc_act/views.py" in abcactname
  18.         data = serializers.serialize('json',abcactDS)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py" in serialize
  129.     s.serialize(queryset, **options)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py" in serialize
  79.         for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  258.         self._fetch_all()

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1074.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  52.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  852.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/home/deep/workspace/src/abcJournal/abcjournal/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /abc/trade/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'table2.id' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: It's recommended to use capitalised names for models, e.g. `Table1` and `Table2`. It will make your question easier to understand for other Django users.

Comment: Will take care next time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
table2.objects.filter(xyzname__icontains='pineapple') \
              .select_related('abcid__abcid',
                              'abcid__abcName',
                              'abcid__abcyear')
```

`select_related` [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: i tried this but getting an error-'abcid' does not resolve to an item that supports prefetching

Comment: same error and what about 'table2s' it can be any thing or i have to write it as it is.

Comment: Sorry I deleted what I edited, I made a mistake. I edited my answer. Please try `select_related`.

Comment: Getting error-Non-relational field given in select_related: 'ptcid'. Choices are: (none)

Comment: Are you sure you typed the field names correctly? It's like `abcid__field1`, `abcid__field2` in `select_related` and `abcid` is the `ForeignKey` name in `table2`.

Comment: error-:Non-relational field given in select_related: 'abcid'. Choices are: (none)
Mycode-:table2.objects.filter(xyzname__icontains= 'pineapple').select_related('abcid__abcyear')

Comment: Hmm, donno, it should work. Maybe you use `inspectdb` to create those models?

Comment: i did that only.somehow i am not able to call the foreign key reference field :(

Answer (score 1):

In Django, the normal approach is to return a queryset of objects from one model, not objects that contain fields from multiple models.

```
objects = table2.objects.filter(xyzname__icontains= 'pineapple')
```

You can then loop through the objects, and follow the foreign key from table2 to table1 with `obj.abcid`

```
for obj in objects:
    print(obj.xyzname, obj.abcid.id, obj.abcid.abcName, obj.abcid.abcyear)
```

To speed up your query, you can use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), so that Django does the inner join.

```
objects = table2.objects.filter(xyzname__icontains= 'pineapple').select_related('abcid')
```

This still returns a queryset of table2 objects. You loop through them and access the foreign keys in the same way as above.

Comment: Actually it is giving error for the id not abcid i.e abcid.id which is referring the primary table.I am having the same problem that i can't refer the primary field using the foreign key reference.

Comment: Since the primary key of table1 is `abcid`, it should be `obj.abcid.abcid`. Another option would be to use `obj.abcid_id`.

Comment: i have recreated the models using inspectdb and now it is giving me an exception-: Unknown column 'table2.id' in 'field list '" when i am trying to execute -: table2.objects.get(pk=207). Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: To understand the error, you need to show the full traceback, and your updated models.

Comment: i have updated the full traceback and for the model there is no change.Please look if u can help.

Comment: What is the code for the view that is triggering the error.

Comment: Just to weigh in on this:- Are you sure the db is synced and you're migrating any and all changes your making? I'll probably provide a better answer when I'm home and can test this.

Comment: yes i migrate all the changes every time i change the model and  in the view part i am just calling-: table2.objects.filter(xyzname__icontains= 'pineapple').I dont have a primary key in the table 2 is that the reason for  table2.id  field error ?

Comment: [Django requires all models to have exactly one primary key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields). You haven't set `primary_key=True` for any fields, so Django assumes there is a column `id`. If this column doesn't exist then you'll get errors.